# When Jesus says "Amen, Amen I say to you" is that a hint that the next thing He says should be taken "more literally" than usual?

Tags: catholicism, words-of-jesus, literalism

At my son's confirmation class last night the teacher told him that our priest told him (and I haven't confirmed this with the priest) that whenever Jesus says "Amen Amen I say to you", that this is a hint that the next words He says should be taken literally.

For instance

> Amen, amen, I say to you, whoever believes has eternal life. I am the bread of life. Your ancestors ate the manna in the desert, but they died; this is the bread that comes down from heaven so that one may eat it and not die. I am the living bread that came down from heaven; whoever eats this bread will live forever; and the bread that I will give is my flesh for the life of the world.
>
> John 6:47-51 NAB

[And several more](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=NABRE&quicksearch=amen+amen&begin=50&end=50)

This was news to me and I'm gonna go hunt down all those instances, but is this a "well known sort of thing" when it comes to Biblical scholarship especially in Catholic circles?

The Catholic understanding of scripture is that all scripture is first and foremost to be interpreted literally, but is the emphasis on amen amen, supposed to stand out and how does it stand out in relations to places where Jesus doesn't place this sort of emphasis, do they form the basis for a higher order of commandments?

Comment: I asked a similar question in Dec 2015 , on why Jesus addressed Martha twice before speaking to her . See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45987/

Comment: It would help if the question included some example scriptures where Jesus says "Amen Amen I say to you".

Comment: Matthew, Mark, and Luke record "truly" statements.  Only John contains "truly, truly" and that 25 times.  For starters, 5:25 and 8:51 are tough to take literally.

Comment: @Mike gotcha, in the New American Bible, it's Amen, Amen

Comment: Seems irrelevant, TBH. Instead, Jesus just seems to be intensifying his previously made point, in whatever manner it seems appropriate to him, literal or figurative. Compare interactions with Nicodemus at John 3.

Comment: Or does your priest believe we literally will enter our mother's wombs to be born again?

Comment: But it makes a great, out-of-context, speaking-through-my-hat sort of argument for the Catholic view of the Eucharist at John 6!

Comment: If we look carefully at the Catholic [4 senses of Scripture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_senses_of_Scripture), your priest can STILL maintain that it is "literal" in ALL verses, if what he means by "literal" is one of the 4 senses, instead of "literal" as contrasted to "figurative".  Just because it is "figurative" in other John verses doesn't make it necessarily "typological", "tropological" or "analogigical".  So I think the problem is with multiple meaning of "literal" :-).  I might ask him what he means by "literal" and ask **him** about the Amen, Amen in other John verses.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple that's the conundrum, the person who was saying this to the catechism students probably didn't realize that the literal sense is the light under which all other senses are understood.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think that works. If you think 'Truly, truly, I am the gate' is literal, then 'literal' doesn't mean much of anything.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple In the link you provide, the 'literal' sense is tied to an historical understanding. It doesn't apply very well when discussing verses where Jesus is speaking (except to hold He literally spoke those words, but that's not what anyone cares about in this sort of debate).

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Honestly, I'm still hazy myself about this "literal" business, preferring to research books & papers first (maybe for the next year, as I have a stack of things to learn).  But in case you didn't get the chat notice, let's continue the discussion [in the Upper Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62485544#62485544).

Answer (score 1):

No, 'Amen, amen' is a hint that what He's saying is important ("Pay attention!"), and He is about the intensify his point - whether it's to be understood literally or figuratively.

Consider John 3:3-5 (Berean Standard Bible, 'Truly, truly' = 'Amen, amen').

> Jesus replied, “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can see the kingdom of God unless he is born again.” 4 “How can a man be born when he is old?” Nicodemus asked. “Can he enter his mother’s womb a second time to be born?” 5 Jesus answered, “Truly,
> truly, I tell you, no one can enter the kingdom of God unless he is
> born of water and the Spirit."

Jesus is not confirming Nicodemus' literal and wooden misunderstanding of what Jesus is saying at John 3:3.

Or consider John 1:50-51.

> "Jesus said to him, “Do you believe just because I told you I saw you
> under the fig tree? You will see greater things than these.” 51 Then He
> declared, “Truly, truly, I tell you, you will all see heaven open and
> the angels of God ascending and descending on the Son of Man.”"

Is Heaven going to 'literally' open, like a trap door? No, that's a wooden understanding of what Jesus is saying here.

Or consider John 5:19

> "So Jesus replied, “Truly, truly, I tell you, the Son can do nothing
> by Himself, unless He sees the Father doing it. For whatever the
> Father does, the Son also does."

Is Jesus "literally" seeing the Father, who is Spirit and has no form, doing things? Sounds more like a figurative way to describe Jesus understanding something.

Or John 8:34

> "Jesus replied, “Truly, truly, I tell you, everyone who sins is a
> slave to sin."

Is one "literally" a slave? No, one is a slave in a spiritual or figurative sense.

Or John 8:51

> "Truly, truly, I tell you, if anyone keeps My word, he will never see
> death."

People who keep Jesus' word die - this again is meant in a figurative or spiritual sense.

Or John 10:7

> "So He said to them again, “Truly, truly, I tell you, I am the gate
> for the sheep."

Is Jesus "literally" a gate, made of iron, say? No, again this is meant in a figurative and spiritual sense.

Or John 12:24

> "Truly, truly, I tell you, unless a kernel of wheat falls to the
> ground and dies, it remains only a seed; but if it dies, it bears much
> fruit."

Are Jesus' followers "literally" kernels of wheat? Do wheat kernels "literally" die when they fall to the ground?

To these, of course, can be added examples where Jesus says 'Amen, amen' but He is talking literally. The 'Amen, amen' doesn't 'hint' one way of the other, it just is used to emphasize an important truth will be spoken, whether literal or figurative.

Comment: What translation of the Bible is that?

Comment: Berean Standard.

Comment: @PeterTurner It's 'amen amen'. You can go to the Greek. https://biblehub.com/texts/john/3-5.htm

Comment: OK - I think we might have different opinions about what "born again" means or different opinions about what literal means.

Comment: @PeterTurner How so? Is one literally born again as Nicodemus describes it?

Comment: no, not as Nicodemus describes it, which is why Jesus is kind enough to clarify the point He's making.

Comment: Why is a spiritual sense differentiated from a literal sense?  I can understand spiritual vs. physical or literal vs figurative but a thing can be  spiritually literal just as easily as physically literal.  Jesus literally is that by which entrance may be had.  He is not a literal physical gate but He is the literal spiritual gate.

Comment: @MikeBorden Because the primary senses of 'gate' and 'born' are not spiritual.

Comment: @MikeBorden Those terms are extended by Jesus, and so Jesus is a gate figuratively.

Comment: @MikeBorden You can say  Jesus is actually a spiritual gate. You can even say he is literally a 'spiritual gate'. But you can't say he is literally a 'gate'. The spiritual is distinguished from the literal in *these examples*, but of course someone can be literally a spiritual thing.

Comment: "But you can't say he is literally a 'gate'."  Isn't "physical" implied here making the distinction between spiritual and physical rather than spiritual and literal.

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes, the literal sense of 'gate' is a 'physical gate'.

Comment: Unless you are speaking of heavenly things, in which case the literal sense of gate is a heavenly gate.  John 3:12  In the heavenly realm the physical is the figure as in, man created in the image of God and not the other way around.  The great condescension is the heavenly becoming physical so that we could "see" the heavenly.

Comment: @MikeBorden No, just wrong. Or then the literal sense of anything can be anything else, and there is no figurative sense.

Comment: Spiritual and figurative are not the same.

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes, some words have a literal, spiritual sense. 'Gate' is not one of them!

Answer (score 1):

When Jesus says, "amen". (“ἀμὴν”), it simply adds emphasis to what he is about to say.  Amen is from the Hebrew אָמַן,(or  אֲמַן, ܐܡܢ in Syriac and Aramaic). It simply means, "This is firmly established". And from that one can see how it can commonly mean, "trustworthy/faithful, etc."

According to the Bible software, *Accordance*, Amen (“ἀμὴν”) appears 138 times.

Much the same as "amen" is the particle in the Greek, "ἰδοὺ".  That word appears 260 times in the NT. It is translated as "look!/behold!"  The same sort of word in Hebrew, "hin-ay" (הִנֵּה) occurs 766 times.  Both of these words (amen & look) serve pretty much the same purpose: We are to pause and consider what is just about to be spoken.

Very often, in English, the "look!" particles are omitted (especially in the Gospel acc. to Mark) since the repetition seems tedious to English ears.

Hope that helps.